# Is there a WebRTC RTCSwarmConnection architecture?

Tags: webrtc, streaming, p2p, swarm

I would like to create an audio (mic) and video (camera) chat room with 12 people using webRTC.  I understand signalling and the need for external services like ICE & STUN to help peers connect with each other.

But I don't want to use a full mesh architecture where everyone connects to everyone else because it is less efficient.  I don't want to use expensive TURN relay services.  I want the swarm to propagate the streams automatically so that if a direct connection isn't possible, the network routes the stream packets via peers automatically using encapsulation.

I don't want to use star architecture because I don't want a bottleneck peer.

I would like a peer to connect to maybe 2 or 3 other peers (max) and broadcast their media across the network without worrying about the relaying between peers.  The routing would obviously need to be controlled by some service but I can't see that it's possible to do the stream encapsulation with RTCPeerConnection.  Since WebRTC only allows for a RTCPeerConnection object (1 peer to 1 peer) and a peer would need to distinguish where the incoming stream is coming from and whether it needs to be relayed to another peer.

Is there a technology that extends WebRTC to allow for this more bandwidth efficient architecture?

Comment: if there was, do you think people would bother with servers?

Comment: You still need a public orchestration server to control how the swarm network routes data packets.  That would probably be based on heuristics like available bandwidth, best route from peer A to peer B. etc.  Is that an AdHoc network? I am just struggling with the terminology.  I just wanna know what it's called so I can google it :D

Comment: What do you mean "stream encapsulation"? Architecture seems up to you. I don't see any limitation here. [Relay sample](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/multiple-relay/).

Comment: Mesh does not scale well, but you don't need every possible connection for a p2p network to function.  If peer A sends their video stream to peer B, how does peer B route the stream of peer A on to peers C, D & E?  And how would peer C know that peer B is forwarding peer A stream?  Or is this all done under the hood transparently?

Comment: webrtc only defines a connection between two ends. What you build on top of that is up to you.